# How I can install FTB modpacks to MultiMC 5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I want to keep all of my minecraft instances in same place, and I want to add my FTB instances to [MultiMC 5](http://multimc.org).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible.**

MultiMC 5 has a built in way to track your FTB instances. However, you will still need to use the FTB launcher to download packs and updates.

In order to "Track FTB instances" You need to open the MultiMC 5 options dialog by clicking the "Computer with a Screwdriver" button in the top toolbar.

[image: MultiMC 5 options button]

Next, In the window that opens, you need to Tick the check box next to "Track FTB Instances." Then you will need to tell it where you installed FTB to. Note: This is the folder that has all of the mod packs downloaded to and has the `FTB_Launcher.exe` and `FTB_Launcher.jar` files in it.

[image: MultiMC 5 options dialog]
[image: FTB Install Folder]

Once you've done that, you will be able to see, and launch your FTB instances from MultiMC 5.

[image: MultiMC 5 with tracked FTB instances]

Keep on gaming,

~tarper24

Comment: is there a way to use a ftb modpack downloaded manually as a zip from their website and not use the ftb launcher or curse launcher at all?
for example use the release file downloaded from https://www.feed-the-beast.com/projects/ftb-infinity-evolved/files and install that directly to a new or existing instance in multimc.

Comment: It looks possible, but the way they set their zip file up makes it a little more involved. I would suggest making a new question on here! I would love to give a better explanation than the comments will allow!

Comment: asked. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299779/how-to-install-a-ftb-modpack-from-a-zip-file-to-a-multimc-instance-of-minecraft

Comment: I posted an answer, but I did not download all of the mods, so if you could let me know if that way worked, I would appreciate it!