# How to install a FTB modpack from a zip file to a MultiMC instance of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

How can I install a FTB modpack from a zip file downloaded from the FTB website to a MultiMC instance of Minecraft directly, without using either the Curse launcher or the FTB launcher?

This question is related to but distinct from [How i can install FTB modpacks to MultiMC 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/267803/how-i-can-install-ftb-modpacks-to-multimc-5), for which the answer given was downloading the instance with the launcher and tracking the instance in MultiMC. I want to download the zip file of the modpack directly from the FTB website and use that to install FTB onto an instance made and managed entirely through MultiMC, with no use of either Curse or FTB launchers.

As an example, how could the latest release from this page (https://www.feed-the-beast.com/projects/ftb-infinity-evolved/files) be installed into a MultiMC instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing so this way seems to be possible, but please note: I have not done it before, and I did not follow all the way to the end to make sure that it worked.

**First Step:** Locate and Download the modpack you want to install into MultiMC 5, I will be using the one that [b33f3r](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/41981/b33f3r) linked for me (https://www.feed-the-beast.com/projects/ftb-infinity-evolved/files). Then, extract the downloaded zip file.

[image: FTB Infinity Evolved download page]

**Second Step:** Open MultiMC 5, and Create a new Instance.

[image: New Instance button in MultiMC 5]

Remember to give it a name, so that you know what it is. Don't forget to set the Minecraft version to the version of the modpack. In this case, it's 1.7.10.

[image: MultiMC 5 new instance dialog]
[image: MultiMC 5 select instance version dialog]

**Third Step:** Install Forge so that the instance can run the modpack.

[image: Edit instance button in MultiMC 5]
[image: MultiMC 5 edit instance dialog]

Be sure to select the release for the version of Minecraft the pack is in. MultiMC should only show you the versions compatible with the Minecraft version of the instance, but double check. I also recommend using the versions with the Star next to them, as those are the latest recommended builds.

[image: MultiMC 5 install Forge dialog]

**Fourth Step:** Be sure to run the instance at least once now, so that MultiMC will download the base files of Minecraft and Forge. Then you'll want to copy the files from the "override" folder of the modpack zip file we extracted earlier to the "minecraft" folder of the instance we just made. **Remember** we want to copy the folders inside of the "override" folder, **not** the "override" folder itself.

[image: Copy contents of "override" folder in modpack download to "minecraft" folder in instance]

**Fifth Step:** Download the rest of the mods! This will probably take awhile, but all of the mods appear to be listed on the modpack page under Relations>Dependencies. You'll need to download each mod individually and place them inside of the mods folder in your MultiMC instance. This is the step I didn't do as it would be too time-consuming, which is why most people prefer to use the FTB Launcher.

[image: FTB Infinity Evolved dependencies page.]

Keep on Gaming,

~tarper24

Comment: this answer does replicate the modpack in the most significant ways, but fails to replicate the careful adjustments made by the creators to maintain balance between the mods and remove duplication. the files responsible for those adjustments are not included in this method. with the release of newer versions of multimc thirdparty modpacks are now natively supported.